# AngularJS HTTP request error handling

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I've seen different examples of Restful API facotires error handling and this is a bit confusing. Here is two examples:

**A**

```
angular.module('app').controller('userCtrl', function($scope, User) {
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.error = '';

    User.getUsers().then(function(response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
        $scope.error = 'Users not found';
    })
});

angular.module('app').factory('User', function($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.getUsers = function() {
        return $http.get('url-here').then(function(response) {
            return response;
        });
    }

    return service;
});
```

**B**

```
angular.module('app').controller('userCtrl', function($scope, User) {
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.error = '';

    User.getUsers().then(function(response) {
        if(response.status == 404) {
            $scope.error = 'Users not found';
        } else {
            $scope.users = response.data;
        }
    });
});

angular.module('app').factory('User', function($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.getUsers = function() {
        return $http.get('url-here', function(response) {
            return response;
        }, function(response) {
            return response;
        });
    }

    return service;
});
```

Which one is best practice? Like, if users not found, I would
like to tell that there is no users, and if there is internal server error (500), I would like to tell something like "Something went wrong, try again later".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. Both A and B are erronoeus with option B being worse.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question @georgeawg

Comment: Just delete this question and write a new one that has only one example to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option **A**, for two reasons:

- It is explicit that an error has occured.
- You can personalize these errors depending on the page that they appear in (you might handle a `404` error differently depending on the page or component the user is in).

Then, you can use a `switch` statement to serve specific messages, based on the error code like so:

```
User.getUsers().then(function(response) {

    $scope.users = response.data;

}, function(response) { // error has occured

    switch(response.status) {

        case "404":
            $scope.error = "Users not found.";
            break;

        case "403":
            $scope.error = "You do not have permission to view these users.";
            break;

        case "500":
            $scope.error = "We are having server issues. Please try again in 10 minutes.";
            break;
    }
});
```